# Como listar na View o que aparece no console?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

Tenho esta rotina:

```
 $scope.array1 = window.localStorage.getItem("tipos_pagamentos");

    var as_formas_pag = $scope.array1.split(';');        


   for (var i = 0; i < as_formas_pag.length; i++){         
      $scope.array2 = as_formas_pag[i];
       console.log($scope.array2);
   }
```

Que me retorna no console os nomes certos:

```
Dinheiro
Cartão Visa Crédito
Cartão Master Crédito
```

Como faço o ng-repeat e imprimir na View estes resultados?

Estou fazendo desta forma, mas tá errado, não imprime:

```
<ion-list ng-repeat="r in array2 track by $index">
              <ion-radio ng-model="checkItems[r.i]" ng-value="'{{r.i}}'">{{r.i}}</ion-radio>             
          </ion-list> 

          <button class="button button-full button-assertive" ng-click="pegaFormaPagamento(checkItems[r.i])"  >
              CONTINUAR
          </button>
```

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mude seu código do `controller` para:

```
var tipos = window.localStorage.getItem("tipos_pagamentos");
$scope.tipos= tipos .split(';');
```

E altere seu HTML para o seguinte:

```
<div class="list list-inset" ng-repeat="tipo in tipos">
  <ion-radio ng-model="escolhido" ng-value="$index">{{tipo}}</ion-radio>
</div>
```

Comment: Desta forma ele imprime somente as letras do primeiro item.

Comment: @Ramos ajustei, da uma olhada se assim te atende